# How to change state after resetting a form?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a react form.  The user fills out the form and submits the form but there is an error when submitting.  The error is displayed. When the user hits the reset button, I would like that error to disappear. How do I do that? So once the user resets the form, I would like the form to be new. I have included all the code.

Here's my code:

```
class VehiclePage extends React.Component{
defaultState = { errors: [], tag: null, vin: null, location: null, message: 
null, msg: null};
 constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state=this.defaultState;
        this.submitVehicle=this.submitVehicle.bind(this);
        this.resetFromState=this.resetFromState.bind(this);
        this.validateForm = this.validateForm.bind(this);

      }


 resetFromState= ()=>{
     this.setState({
           ...this.defaultState});
    }

  validateForm(tag, vin, location){
     const errors=[];
     if (tag==''){
         errors.push("Please enter vehicle's RFIDTAG.");
     }else if (vin==''){
         errors.push("Please enter the vehicle's VIN.");
     }else if(vin.length<17){
             errors.push("VIN must be longer than 17 characters.");
     }else if(location==''){
         errors.push("Please enter vehicle's location.");
     }
     return errors;
 }

      submitVehicle(tag, vin, location){
       let msg;
         let errors=this.validateForm(tag, vin, location);
         console.log("tag:", tag);

         if(errors.length>0){
             this.setState({errors: errors});
             console.log("error: ", errors);
             return;
         }else{

       this.setState({errors: []});
             var input={
                     rfidtag: tag,
                     vin: vin,
                     vehzone: location
             };
             console.log("the object is: ", input);
            this.props.createVehicle(input);

          if(this.props.message != ''){
              console.log("SERVER ERROR!!!");


          }
         }
       }

      render(){
          const {errors} = this.state;
           return(
                    <div>
                    <AddVehicle submitVehicle={this.submitVehicle} 
   resetFromState={this.resetFromState} />
                        <div><font color="red">{errors}</font></div>
                        <h4>{this.props.message}</h4>



                    </div>

                )
      }
 }


    const mapStateToProps=(state, ownProps) => {
        console.log("state in vehicle page is: ",state);

          return{
              vehicle: state.vehicle,
              message: state.vehicleReducer.message,
              error: state.vehicleReducer.error
          }
      };

      const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
          return {
              createVehicle: vehicle => 
  dispatch(vehicleActions.createVehicle(vehicle))
          }
      };


   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(VehiclePage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it. I created an action called reset and called it when the reset button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

To reset your form you'll need to add the `value` attribute to your from elements like `input`

```
<input value={this.state.formValue1} ...>
```

Then when you want to reset them, set them back to their default value

```
this.setState({ formValue1: "", formValue2: "" });
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm using refs. <input  type="text" name="rfidtag" ref={this.rfidtagInput} /> And when I am resetting the form I call the resetForm function which is: 
       resetForm=(e)=>{
  
  document.getElementById("vehForm").reset();
  props.resetFromState();
}    This actually clears out the form but the error from the  mapstatetoprops is still displayed.  Is there any way to refresh the whole form when it has been reset?

Comment: I am using mapstatetoprops to get the error.  How do I delete this error after it has been reviewed?  How do I do it by using the resest button?

Comment: After it has been reviewed, perform another redux action to remove it from the Redux store

Comment: How do I do that??